# Clear the textbox for Html.TexboxFor by embedded x button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to have x button in the textbox so text inside can be cleared when user clicks on it.

The project is ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.8.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CrewId)
```

Comment: hope you get the workaround. If not, take a cross icon from the font awesome or a small png and place it beside the textbox then using css make sure of the position. Now with jquery, you can clear the value of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I am not allowed to use font awesome  but below is the solution that worked for me.

```
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="btn-group has-feedback has-clear">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                <a id="searchclear3"
                                   class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle form-control-feedback form-control-clear"
                                   style="pointer-events:auto; text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer;"
                                   onclick="$(this).prev('input').val('');return false;">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```